# sending email to gmail account locally with xampp, no error but the email does not arrive

Tags: php, windows-7, smtp, gmail, xampp

as in the subject ..!

i configured my file as follows

in php.ini

```
  SMTP =smtp.gmail.com
  smtp_port = 587
  sendmail_from = my adress@gmail.com
  sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and in the sendmail.ini

```
    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port=587
    smtp_ssl=tls
    auth_username=(my adress @gmail.com)
    auth_password=( here my gamil account password )
```

to be clear you can see my php code here!

```
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n";
      $headers .="From: my adress @gmail.com"."\r\n";

       $subject = "Your New Password";
       $message = "Your new password is as follows:
        ----------------------------
        Password: $emailpassword
         ----------------------------
        Please make note this information has been encrypted into our database 

        This email was automatically generated."; 



      if(!mail($forgotpassword, $subject, $message, $headers)){
         die ("Sending Email Failed, Please Contact Site Admin! ($site_email)");
      }else{
           print'New Password Sent!.';
     }
```

what i get when i send is  New Password Sent!.

with no error 
like if really it has been sent 
but when i check the email there's no message !!

NOTE: i'm running on windows-7

Thank you.

Comment: Locally your not allowed to contact the gmail SMTP server. You can only acces the SMTP server of your own internet provider.

Comment: @RTB thank you ..then,  I guess I will postpone the test untill i upload it to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locally your not allowed to contact the gmail SMTP server. You can only acces the SMTP server of your own internet provider. You can however install a simple SMTP server locally [like this one](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html).

In some networks this will allow you to send mail locally from xampp to your local installed SMTP server and from there on to the internet.

Comment: thank you ! but could you tell me how i would configure it ? in php.ini as i'm new to this stuff :$

Comment: thank you ! but could you tell me how i would configure it ? in php.ini as i'm new to this stuff :$

Comment: There's no need to configure the php.ini just use a library like this: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php This also generates all the header code for you. That saves a lot of coding.